# Pull out multiple elevation points from an ISurface

Tags: arcobjects

I have an `ISurface` object and wish to pull out several elevations with one call; instead of using the `GetElevation(IPoint)` method.

The ISurface is representing a dem with 30m cell size.

Is there an `ISurface` method that pulls out several elevations with one call?

Is there another way of pulling elevations from a dem?  A query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a polyline from your points and call [ISurface.InterpolateShapeVertices](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/InterpolateShapeVertices_Method/002500000888000000/).  Then cast to IPointCollection and loop through each vertex to get its Z value.

Comment: +1, I like it.  I'll give it a shot and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: It worked great and this process took much less time to populate 40,000 point elevations.  Thanks!